# How can spark infer dataset automatically after join of two datasets?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming

Is it possible for spark to automatically infer the schema and convert a Dataframe to a Dataset without the programmer having to create a case class for each join?

```
    import spark.implicits._
    case class DfLeftClass(
        id: Long,
        name: String,
        age: Int
                 )
    val dfLeft = Seq(
      (1,"Tim",30),
      (2,"John",15),
      (3,"Pens",20)
    ).toDF("id","name", "age").as[DfLeftClass]

    case class DfRightClass(
                            id: Long,
                            name: String,
                            age: Int
                            hobby: String
                          )
    val dfRight = Seq(
      (1,"Tim",30,"Swimming"),
      (2,"John",15,"Reading"),
      (3,"Pens",20,"Programming")
    ).toDF("id","name", "age", "hobby").as[DfRightClass]

    val joined: DataFrame = dfLeft.join(dfRight) // this results in DataFrame instead of a Dataset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stay within the Dataset API, you can use [joinWith](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#joinWith%5BU%5D(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D,condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5B(T,U)%5D). This function returns a Dataset of tuples containing both sides of the join:

```scala
val joined: Dataset[(DfLeftClass, DfRightClass)] = dfLeft.joinWith(dfRight,
                          dfLeft.col("id").eqNullSafe(dfRight.col("id")))
```

Result:

```
+-------------+--------------------------+
|_1           |_2                        |
+-------------+--------------------------+
|{1, Tim, 30} |{1, Tim, 30, Swimming}    |
|{2, John, 15}|{2, John, 15, Reading}    |
|{3, Pens, 20}|{3, Pens, 20, Programming}|
+-------------+--------------------------+
```

From here you can either continue working with the tuples or you can map the tuples to a third case class.

Comment: Not really answer, werner. Its like someone asking for cheese and you saying we do have prunes, though.

Comment: @thebluephantom well, I think it's the best answer that Spark offers. The only other option that I see would be to switch to Rows, but alexSDE asks for a way to keep the join result as dataset instead of a dataframe. I would consider  a tuple of case classes to be a valid type for a dataset.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I'm curious how we deal with nulls from left and right joins?

Comment: @werner. I think u get my point.

Comment: @m_vemuri it depends a bit on the actual requirements. You could run an outer join (either left, right or full). In this case, one elements of the tuple would be null.